# R - Sustitución de caracteres en vector

Tags: array, r

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en R por mi cuenta, y haciendo unos ejercicios me encuentro con algo que no sé hacer. Me piden cambiar un caracter por otro ("r" por "s") dentro de un vector que contiene nombres, hasta ahí bien.

El problema viene después, que me piden volver a hacer el cambio inverso, pero teniendo en cuenta que hay algunos caracteres que previamente ya eran "s", los cuales no hay que cambiar por "r". No sé si me explico.

La única manera que yo he encontrado de solucionarlo es la siguiente:

```
> VectSust <- gsub("r", "s", VectNombres)
```

En esta línea hago la sustitución de "r" por "s", sin problema.

```
> grep("s", VectNombres, value = TRUE)
> grep("s", VectNombres)
> VectSust2 <- c(VectSust[6], VectSust[8])
```

Con estas instrucciones saco qué nombres tenían previamente "s", y sus índices dentro de VectNombres (6 y 8). Después, me las llevo a un nuevo vector auxiliar.

```
> VectSust <- gsub("s", "r", VectSust)
```

Sustituyo “s” por “r” de nuevo en todo el vector.

```
> VectSust[6] <- VectSust2[1]
> VectSust[8] <- VectSust2[2]
```

Vuelvo a asignar las componentes originales a su lugar correspondiente.

Como digo, creo que es un poco chapuza, así que seguro que debe haber una forma mejor de hacerlo, ¿como sería?

Edit: Añado el enunciado:
Sustituye en “VectNombres” las “r” por “s”. Vuelve a cambiar las “s” por las “r” teniendo cuidado en no cambiar las antiguas “s”.

```
VectNombres <- c("Pepe", "Juan", "Eduardo", "Javier", "Ana", "Rosa", "María", "José", "Carmen", "Alberto")
```

Comment: Bienvenido Marcos a Stack Overflow en español, es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad.

Comment: No le veo mucho sentido al ejercicio, tal vez te falte explicar un poco más. Si sustituimos caracteres de cada elemento del vector y luego queremos invertir dicha sustitución, si mantenemos el vector original ya está la respuesta. El único sentido que le veo, es que estés buscando en primer lugar, generar algún tipo de matriz de sustitución (lugares dónde vamos a modificar) y luego reutilizarla para volver todo a los valores originales.

Comment: Por otro lado, describes una solución que tampoco llego a entender del todo que es lo que intentas: Con `VectSust2 <- c(VectSust[6], VectSust[8])` simplemente creas un nuevo vector con los elemento 6 y 8 de `VectSust` y luego `VectSust[6] <- VectSust2[1]` reemplazas el element 6 de `VectSust` por el 1 de `VectSust2[1]`, no entiendo que coincida con la explicación que dás, pero tal vez me este perdiendo algo.

Comment: Trata de enfocarte principalmente en el problema y no en la solución, si te han dado un enunciado escrito agrégalo completo a la pregunta haciendo click en el botón [edit]. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por los comentarios Patricio!
Editaré el mensaje original añadiendo el enunciado. En realidad como dices no tiene mucho sentido, pero son unos ejercicios para aprender el lenguaje e ir practicando, sin un objetivo en concreto.

Comment: En cuanto a la parte de VectSust2, he editado también la pregunta para corregir una errata, pero lo que intento es llevarme los nombres originales que contenían "s" a un vector auxiliar (que la verdad es que no ayuda demasiado, se podría hacer directamente), para luego volver a colocarlos en su sitio una vez cambiadas las "s" por "r"... Como digo, no es exactamente lo que me piden pero no se me ocurre cómo solucionarlo mejor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahora con el ejemplo me queda claro a lo que apunta el ejercicio, y entiendo mejor lo que has intentado: reemplazas las `r` por las `s`, vuelves a reemplazar las `s` por las `r` y por último sobreescribes los dos valores que tienen originalmente una `s`. No está mal, pero tiene una gran limitación, no es una solución genérica, y depende que tu sepas de antemano que valores originalmente tenían un `s`.

Mucho mejor es hacer algo así:

1. Reemplazamos en `VectNombres` las `r` por `s`
2. Con el nuevo vector volvemos los cambios atrás, **pero solo de las cadenas que han cambiado en (1)**

Esto puedes implementarlo así:

```
VectNombres <- c("Pepe", "Juan", "Eduardo", "Javier", "Ana", "Rosa", "María", "José", "Carmen", "Alberto")
NewVect <- sub('r', 's', VectNombres)

# Solo reemplazamos las cadenas modificadas anteriormente   
modificados <- VectNombres != NewVect
NewVect[modificados] <- sub('s', 'r', NewVect[modificados])
```

Con `modificados <- VectNombres != NewVect` generamos un vector lógico que nos dice que elementos hemos modificado del vector original, y solo sobre estos volveremos a hacer un reemplazo.

Notas

- Siendo puristas, esta solución solo funciona si tienen exclusivamente `r` o `s`, si un elemento tuviera ambas esto seguramente no funcionaría.
- Por otro lado recuerda que `sub()` solo reemplaza la primer ocurrencia de cada cadena, si quieres reemplazar todas deberías usar `gsub()`.

Comment: Perfecto, muchísimas gracias! Es justo lo que estaba buscando, no se me ocurrió comparar ambos vectores para encontrar los cambios.